# Ensuring View is in position before display

Tags: ios, uiview

I have code that does:

```
UIImageView *view ;
. . .
view.frame = rect ;
view.image = image ;
```

The goal is to make the image appear in a specific location.

The problem I encounter is that the image assignment  displays first. The image appears where the UIImageView was then snaps to the final location.

How can I ensure that the view is in its desired position before (assigning the image, making visible)?

I forgot to add, the image view is in a UIScrollView. I am also setting the contentOffset property. That could be the display problem. I need to way until both operations are complete before displaying the image.

Let me elaborate more because I was trying something like the first example. I have two image views and I am trying to replace the first with the second.

```
[iview1 removeFromSuperview] ;
iview1.hidden = NO ;
iview1.image = 0 ;


[UIView animateWithDuration:5 animations:
^{
    scrollview.contentOffset = offset ;
    iview2.frame = rect ;
 } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
    iview2.image = image ;
    [scrollview addSubview:iview2] ;
    iview2.alpha = 1.0 ;
 }];
```

All executing in the main thread.

Amazingly enough, this has the effect of:

1. Moving image1 to the desired position of image2.
2. image1 image slowly scrolls across the screen.
3. When it hits the final point, it disappears and image2 appears.

If I set the delay to 0, it happens in a flicker.

I am puzzled because I done everything possible to make image2 not visible (removed its image, made it hidden, removed from its superview) but it insists on remaining visible until the scrollOffset is completed.

I know the issues of queuing but, my god, when you've done that much to hide the image, why does it not go away?????

Comment: Why has the image view been added to the scroll view before the location and content are set? Have you tried removing the image view from the scroll view, changing what you need to change then adding it back into the scroll view?

Comment: The answer is that it had just been lying around already attached. However, I did try detaching, setting the scroll offset, attaching---and the same thing occurs.

Answer (score 0):

If the imageView is not working with the simple `removeFromSuperview`, change properties, `addSubview`, then I would suggest making it "disappear", waiting for it to get set and then make it appear again. Something like this:

```
    UIImageView* view;
    ...
    view.alpha = 0.0f;
    UIView animateWithDuration:0.2 animations:^{
        view.frame = rect;
        view.image = image;
    }completion:^(BOOL finished){
        view.alpha = 1.0f;
    }
```

EDIT: Seeing your further edits, I would suggest the following change:

```
[iview1 removeFromSuperview] ;
iview1.hidden = YES;
iview1.image = nil ;

[scrollview addSubview:iview2];
iview2.alpha = 0;
iview2.image = image ; //you could make this assignment in the completion block as well

[UIView animateWithDuration:5 animations:
^{
    scrollview.contentOffset = offset ;
    iview2.frame = rect ;
 } completion:^(BOOL finished) {

    iview2.alpha = 1.0 ;
 }];
```

Hope this solves your problem.

Comment: See my edits. Hope this helps. I've seen generally that modifying frames without the UIView added on screen can lead to a bad_access. Better to have them invisible.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a problem with the animation. The best answer I have is using timing delays.

```
[iview1 removeFromSuperview];

dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(NSEC_PER_SEC * 0.001)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    [UIView animateWithDuration:5 animations:^{
        scrollview.contentOffset = offset;
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(NSEC_PER_SEC * 0.001)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            iview2.frame = rect;
            iview2.image = image;
            [scrollview addSubview:iview2];
        });
    }];
});
```

I know this looks crazy, but the idea is to move the other actions into other run loops so they are not effected by the animation.